# How can we identify whether a function is inlined or not during GDB debugging?

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, inline, compiler-optimization

While debugging a C program using GDB, running the command *bt* would list the function call stack. The later version of GDB displays inlined functions just like non-inlined functions. They appear in backtraces. However from the below article I understand it is possible to differentiate whether the function is inlined or not.

Link - [GDB_Inline_Func](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Inline-Functions.html)

They have quoted -

> You can check whether a function was inlined by using the ***info frame***
>   command.

I am unable to understand how can I interpret the information shown up on executing the command *info frame* to determine whether the current function is inlined function or not.

Comment: Check disassembly if there is function call or not.

Comment: What do you mean by inlined? Do you want to know if the function was **completely** inlined so that every call was replaced with inline code and there is no separate implementation of the function, or do you want to know if the function was inlined **in a certain call** so that that particular call was replaced with inline code but a separate implementation may still exist for other calls?

Comment: @EricPostpischil well... To answer to the point I was referring to the 2nd situation. However, I was in an impression that inlining optimisation happens depending on the calling function's body (if it is small) and not on the caller function.

Comment: Seems I'm not the only one puzzled by this sentence "You can check whether a function was inlined by using the **info frame** command."

Answer (score 0):

For example you can `disassemble [Function]` and if it is inlined you'll get an error